# Calling a Scala function that takes parameter Option[Long] from Java

Tags: java, scala

I have a Scala function that takes a single parameter of type Option[Long].

I want to call this function from Java, but if I try

```
Long num = new Long(5);
scalaFunction(Option.apply(num));
```

I get an error that it was expecting a Option<java.lang.Object> and will not accept my Option<java.lang.Long>.

It will compile and run if I write:

```
scalaFunction((Object) num);
```

However, this feels dirty and probably not the right way to do this...so...what is the right way?

Comment: Long of scala are not Long in java.

Comment: Yeah I figured that much...so what do I do? And why does it work if I cast to Object? (When I debug, I see the correct value in Scala even though I pasted it a Java Long casted as a Java Object)

Comment: Option.apply(scala.Long.unbox(5L)) for example ?

Comment: That's still an Option<java.lang.Long>. I think the problem I am trying to solve is why the function defined in Scala that wants a parameter of type Option[Long] shows up in Java as a function that wants Option<java.lang.Object>. If this is intentional (due to type erasure or something), how am I supposed to work around it and correctly pass an Option[Long] via Java?

Comment: seems to work on my project :        Option<scala.Long> a = Option.apply(scala.Long(5L));

Comment: That's not what I need, the function expects Option<java.lang.Object>. It was defined in Scala as expecting Option[Long].

Comment: I simply do not understand. The function you want to call wants X<Object>, but you insist that it must accept X<Long>. How insane is this?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know how that makes sense either. The actual message is:
scalaFunction (scala.Option<java.lang.Object>) in ScalaClass cannot be applied to scalaFunction (scala.Option<java.lang.Long>)

Answer (score 2):

I think a simple

`Option<scala.Long> a = Option.apply(scala.Long(5L));`

will work :)

Comment: That still doesn't work for me. I understand that that will create an Option<scala.Long>, but from the Java side, the Scala function that I have won't accept that either, it wants Option<java.lang.Object>

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain, but I seem to recall coming across this issue before, and it's down to being unable to sensibly convert the variance annotations from Scala to Java.

Recall that `Option` is defined as `Option[+A]`. If I define a function `foo(x : Option[Long])` then that function will take any `Option[A]` where `A <: Long`. However, there's no easy way of indicating the covariant nature of `Option` to Java, so I think that the compiler just presents it as being a plain `Option<Object>`.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. You confirmed what I thought. What I want to know now is what I'm supposed to do about it. Is it safe to just cast a java Long as an Object and pass that in? Is that a bad idea? Is there a better way?